# How to use CTE with a T-SQL variable in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a T-SQL variable containing another variable and I want to create a CTE based on this T-SQL variable.

I have tried printing the T-SQL variable in CTE but it is not working.

```
declare
    @Hid nvarchar(5),
    @mysql nvarchar(max)

set @Hid = 1

set @mysql = 'SELECT    
                  CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS RptDate,
                  a.[key], 
                  b.[Country], b.AcNumber, b.AcName, 
                  DATEDIFF([d], a.[ItemDate], GETDATE()) AS [IAge],
                  [comment] AS OfficerComment,
                  (SELECT dbo.fnMgrCmnt(2,' + @Hid + ', a.rowid, 1)),
                  c.[firstname] + '' '' + c.[lastname] AS Modifiedby,
                  d.hubId, 
                  '''' AS origin,
                  b.Authname,
                  CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 2), a.amount) AS Amt,
                  b.AcOwner, 
                  a.rowid AS rowid
              FROM [dbo].[T_AccRecon] a 
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[VW_TMain] b ON a.[key] = b.[Key] 
              LEFT JOIN [dbo].[users] c ON a.Modifiedby = c.userId 
              LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Country] d ON b.Country = d.code
                                          AND b.AcOwner = d.hubcode'
```

I want to create a CTE from this `@mysql` variable. I tried with

```
;WITH MY_CTE AS (@mysql)
```

but it is not working. What can be done for this?

Comment: The first thing is that when you build a string it is dynamic sql which means you have to execute the string. The second thing is you need to use parameters instead of executing strings with input. The third thing is I don't think you need dynamic sql here in the first place.

Comment: I second this. Are you just showing an excerpt from something larger? You could easily just run that sql statement directly in your example. Maybe post the larger example, including the CTE.